# Cross-Domain AJAX doesn't send X-Requested-With header

Tags: ajax, http-headers, cross-domain, cors

Create a web service on **http://www.a.com/service.asmx** and send a cross-domain ajax request to it from **http://www.b.com**. Check the headers in **Firebug**, or in **Live HTTP Headers**, or any other plugin you wish.

There is no trace of the **X-Requested-With** HTTP Header field among request headers.

However, if you send an ajax request to the same service from the same domain (say for example **http://www.a.com/about**), you will see that header field.

Why is the **X-Requested-With** header field omitted for cross-domain ajax requests?

**Update:** I know that JSONP calls are not AJAX calls in nature. Thus you won't see any **X-Requested-With** header field, in JSONP calls.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you are using jQuery to do your ajax request, it will not send the header X-Requested-With (HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH) = XMLHttpRequest, because it is cross domain. But there are 2 ways to fix this and send the header:

Option 1) Manually set the header in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://your-url...",
 headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
});
```

Option 2) Tell jQuery not to use cross domain defaults, so it will keep the X-Requested-With header in the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://your-url...",
 crossDomain: false
});
```

But with this, the server must allow those headers, then the server needs to print those headers:

```
print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\n";
print "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type\n";
```

The first line above will avoid the error *"Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."*
The second line will avoid the error *"Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."*

Comment: The first line also allows everyone to do cross domain requests to your server which is not a good idea in general. The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header should be set dynamically by checking the "Origin" header against a whitelist.