# Laravel - cross domain request - barryvdh laravel-cors

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-4, cross-domain

I have problem with cross domain request. I want to send get request via ajax from 'www.second-domain.com' to 'www.first-domain.com/path/to/plugin' and return html code (plugin view).
I install 'barryvdh/laravel-cors' from github in Laravel 4.2 on 'www.first-domain.com'.
**plugin.blade.php**

```
<div id="bookingPlugin">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bookingPlugin">
            <div class="bookingPluginHeader">
                <div class="bookingPluginTxtCenter">REZERWACJA ON-LINE</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bookingPluginContent bookingPluginNoPadding">
                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <div class="bookingPluginButtonContainer">
                    <button id="{{{ $category->CategoryId }}}" class="bookingPluginTxtCenter">{{{ $category->CategoryName }}}</button>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bookingWindow"></div>
<script>
    $.getScript('http://plugins.first-domain.com/bookingWindow.js');
    $.getScript('http://first-domain.com/packages/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js');
    $("head").append(
        "<link href=\"http://first-domain.com/packages/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" type=\"text/css\">"
    );
    $("#bookingPlugin button").click(function(){
        openBookingWindow("{{ $hotelId }}", this.id);
    });
</script>
```

On 'www.second-domain.com' I added the following line to the code. If this line I added to 'www.first-domain.com' it is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://plugins.first-domain.com/book.js"></script>
```

**book.js**

```
$("head").append(
    "<style>"+
        "#bookingPlugin{position:absolute;top:200px;width:100%;z-index:999;}"+
        "#bookingPlugin button{font-size:100%;margin:0;vertical-align:baseline;line-height:normal;text-transform:uppercase;background:#2670b5;}"+
        "#bookingPlugin button{width:100%;cursor:pointer;color:#fff;-webkit-appearance:button;border:1px solid #fff;outline:0;padding:5px;}"+
        "#bookingPlugin button:hover{background:#275DA2}"+
        ".bookingPlugin{width:250px;background-color:#fff;color:#444;border:1px solid #fff;padding:5px}"+
        ".bookingPluginNoPadding{padding:0;}"+
        ".bookingPluginHeader{width:100%;font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #444;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:5px;}"+
        ".bookingPluginTxtCenter{text-align:center;}"+
        ".bookingPluginContent{width:100%;}"+
        ".bookingPluginButtonContainer{width:100%;}"+
    "</style>"
);

$.ajax({
    //send get ajax request to laravel
    type:'get',
    //call to route
    url:'http://www.first-domain.com/path/to/plugin',
    //return data type as html
    dataType:'html'
}).done(function(data){
    //insert returned data into body element
    $("body").append(data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    alert(thrownError);
});
```

**barryvdh/laravel-cors/config.php**

```
'defaults' => array(
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => array(),
    'allowedHeaders' => array(),
    'allowedMethods' => array(),
    'exposedHeaders' => array(),
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => array(),
),

'paths' => array(
    '^/' => array(
        'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
        'allowedHeaders' => array('Content-Type'),
        'allowedMethods' => array('POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'),
        'maxAge' => 3600,
    )
)
```

**EDIT:**
Request headers (www.second-domain.com -> www.first-domain.com)

```
Accept  text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
DNT 1
Host    first-domain.com
Origin  http://www.first-domain.com
Referer http://www.first-domain.com/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
```

Response headers (www.second-domain.com -> www.first-domain.com)

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Mon, 27 Oct 2014 07:49:01 GMT
Server  nginx
Set-Cookie  laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Imtva3...; expires=Mon, 27-Oct-2014 09:49:01 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Vary    Origin
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.17
access-control-allow-origin http://www.first-domain.com
```

Request headers (www.first-domain.com -> www.first-domain.com)

```
Accept  text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Cookie  laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjB1V...; _ga=GA1.2.1119242176.1414394349; _gat=1
DNT 1
Host    first-domain.com
Referer http://first-domain.com/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Response headers (www.first-domain.com -> www.first-domain.com)

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Mon, 27 Oct 2014 07:48:32 GMT
Server  nginx
Set-Cookie  laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImVxd...; expires=Mon, 27-Oct-2014 09:48:32 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.17
```

Comment: So what's the problem? What error messages are reported in the JavaScript console? What error messages are reported in the PHP log? Does the HTTP request look the way you expect in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools? What about the response? Does the response include the allow origin header?

Comment: **Response headers:**
`Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 0
Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date Mon, 27 Oct 2014 07:25:05 GMT
Server nginx
Set-Cookie laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkdLVW14...; expires=Mon, 27-Oct-2014 09:25:05 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Vary Origin
X-Powered-By PHP/5.5.17
access-control-allow-origin http://www.first-domain.com`

Comment: **Request headers:**
`Accept text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
DNT 1
Host first-domain.com
Origin http://www.first-domain.com
Referer http://www.first-domain.com/
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
In www.first-domain.com -> www.first-domain.com request was include the header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest', but on www.second-domain.com -> www.first-domain.com request wasn't this header.
The full answer I found on this topic [Cross-Domain AJAX doesn't send X-Requested-With header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163703/cross-domain-ajax-doesnt-send-x-requested-with-header)