# Laravel Ajax validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I understand how to validate requests by type-hinting the class name in the controller method. However for Ajax requests, [According to the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation), I should validate data in the controller, because using a validator class will redirect rather than send a response.

The main part I'm looking at is this:

> If the incoming request was an AJAX request, no redirect will be
>   generated.  Instead, an HTTP response with a 422 status code will be
>   returned to the browser containing a JSON representation of the validation errors.

However, my controller is as follows:

```
public function update(App\Permission $permission, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'permission_description' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    ...
}
```

And I can't for the life of me get it to respond with JSON. The documentation states that if it fails, it throws an `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationException` exception, but I can't catch it.

Whenever it fails, it always redirects back to the edit page. Obviously I don't want this, I want the json response.

I have just tried "manually writing it out" with the whole `$v = Validator::make($request->all(), ...);` which does work, but what's the point in using the `$this->validate()` way if it doesn't work?

Does the `$this->validate()` method just not work with AJAX and I have to write it the long way each time? Am I doing something wrong?!

Below is what I've tried:

```
public function update(App\Permission $permission, UpdatePermissionRequest $request)
{
   /** Redirects rather than returns JSON if the validation fails **/
}

----------------------------------

public function update(App\Permission $permission, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'permission_description' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    /** AND I've also tried: **/

    try {
        $this->validate($request, ['permission_description' => 'required|string']);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationException $e {
        echo $e; /** Echoing for debug reasons **/
        exit;
    }

    ... 
    /** Still redirects the browser, even if it is an AJAX request **/
}

-----------------------------------------

use Validator;
...
public function update(App\Permission $permission, Request $request)
{
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'permission_description' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    if($v->fails())
    {
        return response()->json(['reply' => false]);
    }

    /** Works **/
}
```

**UPDATE**
The documentation is incorrect. It states that the `$this->validate()` method throws a `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationException` but it doesn't. It throws a `Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException` exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement that the docs say it is best to validate AJAX requests in the controller is simply incorrect.

If you scroll a [bit further down from what you linked](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation) - you'll see this under the FormValidation section

> If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the
>   user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed
>   to the session so they are available for display. If the request was
>   an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be
>   returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation
>   errors.

In other words - there is no reason you cannot do this in a simple FormRequest and simply your code significantly. It will automatically handle the fact it is an AJAX call and return the appropriate HTTP responses.

I do this all the time in my L5 apps - it works flawlessly.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately a cross-domain option in my ajax request was omitting the `X-Requested-With` option on the request, so to the server it looked like it was a standard non-ajax request.

Comment: @Laurence I have a similar question but I guess I need a bit practical solution can you please take a look at my thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780698/how-to-validate-x-editable-request-in-laravel-server-side

Comment: @PhilCross if you got yours working can you please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780698/how-to-validate-x-editable-request-in-laravel-server-side

Answer (score 5):

Simply telling that you want json in the header should also fix this. Laravel checks if the request is ajax of if json is requested.

```
if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson())
{
    return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
}
```

**Solution:**

Add header

Accept: application/json

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it looks like there were 2 contributing factors.

1. The reason it was redirecting instead of responding with JSON is because the X-Requested-With field wasn't set on the AJAX request. This the AJAX wrapper for the application was setup to deal with Cross Domain requests, which seems to strip out the X-Requested-With field, which makes the ultimate request look non-ajax to the server - hence the redirection.
2. The reason why it wasn't catching the `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationException` exception is because that exception is not thrown. If you open up `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequest.php`, and search for the function `throwValidationException()`, it actually throws a `HttpResponseException` instead. I attempted to catch the `HttpResponseException` and it was caught successfully - I assume the documentation is wrong.

The solution was to either remove the cross domain attributes on the ajax request, add the X-Requested-With header manually, as per the [answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163703/cross-domain-ajax-doesnt-send-x-requested-with-header). This would make the application see that it was an AJAX request.

And if you wanted to manually catch the exception, you need to catch the `HttpResponseException`, not the `ValidationException`.

Comment: Having the same issue but i'm a newbie so i would very grateful if you could please show a working example so that i can understand better.