# How to validate X-editable request in laravel (Server side)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, validation

I've managed to get x-editable (https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) to work with a page, in so far as when I click on a field, it displays inline and I can edit it, and I'm able to successfully submit to a POST URI.

The idea here is that I'm sending three key-value pairs:

```
array:3 [▼
  "name" => "name"
  "value" => "mathematics"
  "pk" => "1"
]
```

and my `update()` method catches the array, and it successfully updates the record in the database. But I'm failing to validate the data.

This is how my controller looks:

```
 public function update(Request $request)
{
    //
    $id = $request->pk;
    $subject = Subject::findOrFail($id);

    $rules = array (
        'name' => 'bail|required|max:20|unique:subjects,name,'.$id
    );
```

**This validation pass easily even if I try to fail it**

```
    $validator = Validator::make ( $request->all(), $rules );

    if ($validator->fails ()) {
        return response()->json ( array (

         'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag ()->toArray ()
        ) );
    } else {
        $subject->update([$request->name => $request->value]);
    }
    return response ()->json ( $subject );
 }
```

So it's as if I'm somehow not passing the "correct" Request object to validate()? There is no form submission, but [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) clearly states that:

> Laravel generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code.<sup>[1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-ajax-requests-and-validation)</sup>

Route:

```
Route::post('/subjects/update/', 'SubjectsController@update');
```

script:

```
$('#subjects').editable({
     container:'body',
     selector:'td.name',
     type:'post',
     dataType:'JSON',
     validate:function(value){
        if ($.trim(value) === '') {
           return "Field is required";
        }
     }
});
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-ajax-requests-and-validation</sub>

Comment: I am having a little bit of trouble understanding your question. Your values are being sent over correctly? But the validation is not being run "correctly"?  Is it the max length? The subject relation?

Comment: What are you `"trying to fail it"` with?

Comment: @Henry the `name` field is unique and when I tried to insert a name that already exists it passes the validation can cause and Internal error. Normally when I send ajax request without x-editable and try to fail that validation I'm returned the error message through json, which I catch and display it to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `name` is the field to be edited (the DB column), and `value` is, well, the value. It looks like you are updating the `name` column, so you have to validate the uniqueness of the `value` in the request, not the "name".

Also, I'd suggest you use the `validate` method of your controller (provided by the `ValidatesRequests` trait):

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->pk;
    $subject = Subject::findOrFail($id);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required', // this should be the column to update
        'value' => 'bail|required|max:20|unique:subjects,name,'.$id
    ];        

    $subject->update([$request->name => $request->value]);

    return $subject;
 }
```

Here `validate` will automatically reject with a 422 code and the validation errors in the JSON response. If it passes, it will continue with the update. (`return $subject` also returns a JSON representation of the object in the response.)

Comment: if there is two(2) fields to be validated by the controller(`name`and`another field`) the only option here is to do a conditional statement on the rules right?

Comment: @NathanSiafa yes, you can also use the `required_if` validation rule to check values of another field. However, the fields are always `name` and `value`, are they not?

Comment: @lepeino thanks very much. You cost me a little, but it was worth it.