# Error: Cross origin request block

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, preflight

I am trying to develop a web using PlanGrid API, and i getting cross domain request block error.

```
var apiKey="API KEY";
var password="PASSWORD";
$.ajax({
    url: "https://io.plangrid.com/projects",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(apiKey + ":" + password),
        Accept:'application/vnd.plangrid+json; version=1'
    },
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

After ajax request, i am getting error:

"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401."

Can someone let me know where i am going wrong. thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163703/cross-domain-ajax-doesnt-send-x-requested-with-header

Comment: after making the following changes as said in that post, it didnt work. again same error. thanks thouhg

Comment: you have permissions to access that URL?

Comment: Yes, I do! I am able to access through cURL command through terminal. It gives me proper json response

Comment: Try to install this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en
If it works with this extension then you have permissions issue

Comment: bilal, it does when i install that extension but when i add basic authentication header, it gives me preflight error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing **https** to **http** in ajax and see if it works.
Match the protocol same as your domain that is localhost.
Your localhost is on **http**.